# ORB.destroy() does not cleanup correctly and ORB object instances are not garbage collected

Tags: java, garbage-collection, corba, orb

Problem : ORB.destroy() does not cleanup correctly and ORB object instances are not garbage collected.

This issue was raised with JDK5 and fixed in later releases documented here
http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6354718. We are using JDK7 and still see file descriptor are open for connection and never get release as an immediate workaround we increased OS FB limit (But some day later again this problem will hit us).

For every connection we are seeing this below by using command "lsof -p process-id"

COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME

java    14674     xyz  106u   IPv6             xyz      0t0        TCP *:xyz (LISTEN)

We also tried to run sample program with that are able to see connections are closed with new JDK6 and JDK7 (analyzed connection using TCP Viewer).

Don't understand why helloworld corba program works correctly but not with our application in both cases we are doing:

```
orb.shutdown(true);
orb.destroy();
```

We are also tried with but it doesn't releases connection (where rootNamingContext is instance of NamingContextExt):

```
rootNamingContext._release();
rootNamingContext = null;
System.gc();
```

Comment: Further investigating this using tcpdump we found session get closed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Further investigating this using tcpdump we found connection get closed correctly.